# passing array from one page to another in php

Tags: php

How can I pass array value from one page to another in php and retrieve value of that array in another page.
I have use array_push function to insert value of database in array using loop as below.

```
array_push($file_names,$row['sVoiceFileName'])));
```

Now, I want to pass $file_array variable to another page. I have try below code to pass array but doesn't works.It only shows Array in the url.

```
echo "<a href='download.php?voice=". $file_names."'> ". "Download All"."</a>";
```

Is there any alternative way to pass array to another page or using post method. And How can I retrieve value in another page.
 Here I am trying to download all the file included in array as zip. For that I have function

```
function zipFilesAndDownload($file_names,$archive_file_name,$file_path)
```

in another page. I need to pass $file_names array to that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
echo "<a href='download.php?voice=". impode(';', $file_names)."'> ". "Download All"."</a>";

function zipFilesAndDownload($file_names,$archive_file_name,$file_path)
{
$file_names = explode(';', $file_names);
}
```

implode/explode you can also replace by json_encode/json_decode, serialize/unserialize, just on your wish.

Comment: in this case you should care about occurance of ; symbol in array values.

Answer (score 0):

you can use for instance the function [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

and pass returned result as POST or GET parameter

then apply `unserialize` function to that value
and you will get the original array